# "The underlying connection was closed" error on when calling WebClient.DownloadString() from .Net 4.0 app to .Net Core 3.1 Web API

Tags: vb.net, .net-4.0, webclient, webrequest, webapi

I have an old .Net 4.0 WinForms app (in VB) that now has the requirement that it needs to get some data from a Web API. The Web API is written in .Net Core 3.1 and is hosted on Azure App Service.

I initially tried using HttpClient, but was getting some weird errors, and I think it's because HttpClient is really for .Net 4.5 and up. So I've now tried using WebClient, as well as WebRequest, but both give me this error:

> "The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on
>   a send." "Unable to read data from the transport connection: An
>   existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host."

Here is my code:

```
Dim uri As String = $"{apiUrl}/AzureStorage/Sas?section={section}&recordId={recordId}&filename={filename}"

Using client As New WebClient()
    client.Headers.Add("clientId", clientId.ToString())
    Dim response As String = client.DownloadString(uri)
End Using
```

I realized I have CORS enabled on the API, so for that particular controller, I have disabled CORS by adding the [DisableCors] decorator to the top of the controller, but it's made no difference. CORS is also disabled in Azure App Service, so I don't think it's a CORS issue.

That very same API endpoint is being called from an Angular 8 app with no problems. It even works when I call it from Postman. But I get said exception when called from the VB app.

The response is supposed to be this JSON object:

```
{
    "filename": null,
    "sasUri": "https://propworx.blob.core.windows.net/devtest/sent_items/1/Repair Report (2).pdf?sv=2019-02-02&sr=b&sig=mO1nfJOc86aug9kESHciPs%2F1H04%2FNw7vdTiGYab3XJg%3D&se=2020-01-25T06%3A32%3A39Z&sp=rcw",
    "blobUri": "https://propworx.blob.core.windows.net/devtest/sent_items/1/Repair Report.pdf",
    "container": "devtest",
    "storageServicesVersion": "2019-02-02",
    "startTime": null,
    "expiryTime": "2020-01-25T06%3A03%3A08Z",
    "resource": "b",
    "permissions": "rcw",
    "ipRange": null,
    "protocol": null,
    "signature": "5CYUJ4oHMexx19EOnooyrwpeKrbJyyDGLVMf5Sl5V1s%3D",
    "token": "sv=2019-02-02&sr=b&sig=5CYUJ4oHMexx19EOnooyrwpeKrbJyyDGLVMf5Sl5V1s%3D&se=2020-01-25T06%3A03%3A08Z&sp=rcw",
    "storageResource": null
}
```

Here's a screenshot of Postman making the request:

[image]

Any ideas?

**EDIT:**

Ok, if I run the Web API locally on my PC (i.e. I load up the solution in Visual Studio and I hit the Start button), then the VB app can connect to it and everything works (using http://localhost:50504/ instead of https://propworx-api-san.azurewebsites.net). So I think for some reason the VB app cannot call the API when it's on Azure (but funny enough, Postman, also running on my PC, can)

Comment: Well, the API is called, otherwise you won't have *An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host*. The Remote Host closes the connection, so the Host was reached. Have you tried to simply add `ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12` or (`ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = CType(3072, SecurityProtocolType)` with FW 4.0) before WebClient creates the connection? (You my also need to validate the Server certificate(s) *manually*)

Answer (score 1):

Thank you jimmi for your comment. I followed your suggestion, and added the following line just before the client.DownloadString(uri) line:

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = CType(3072, SecurityProtocolType
```

and it worked! So the code now looks like this:

```
Dim uri As String = $"{apiUrl}/AzureStorage/Sas?section={section}&recordId={recordId}&filename={filename}"

Using client As New WebClient()
    client.Headers.Add("clientId", clientId.ToString())
    ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = CType(3072, SecurityProtocolType
    Dim response As String = client.DownloadString(uri)
End Using
```